# Is there a way to make components (not elements) draggable in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk, dragdropmodule

Im using the Angular CDK drag and drop module, it works well on html elements like div, p and such. but for some reason when i put a cdkDrag directive on a component, it doesnt work.

```
<!-- WORKS -->    
<div cdkDrag>content</div>    

<!-- DOESNT WORK -->
<my-component cdkDrag></my-component>
```

another thing i noticed is that every component in angular have width and height set to `auto` (basically 0x0), unless i edit the css and put `display: block` on the component style

Comment: And if you wrap the component with a div? I believe it has to do with the way the component is compiled to html.

Comment: And if you set them to block, can you then drag them ?

Comment: i wrapped the component with a div, it works, thx. for some reason when i used 'block', the component's width became 100%, so i used 'inline-block'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component is a custom tag. Within a browser this is treated as an 'unknown' tag, and made to have the default display of `inline`. This will also cause the dimensions to be 0x0 if you add block elements in there.

To overcome this, you should make it `display: block` or `inline-block` or `flex` (or whatever suits you) to make it also draggable. You can make a global class if this doesn't break the layout of the rest of your draggables:

```
.cdkDrag {
  display: inline-block;
}
```